# Useless part in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization

I have a generic code that generates **Elasticsearch** query.

Is there a performance penalty to have useless part in an **Elasticsearch** query :

In this example, the empty `"bool" : {}` part

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "a": "a"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "b": "b"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Because it could be written without `must` and only one `should`

```
"post_filter": {
  "bool": {
    "should": {
      …
    }
  }
}
```

Or another example :

```
"post_filter": {
  "term": {
    "a": "a"
  }
}
```

is it equivalent in performance with

```
"post_filter": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "term": {
        "a": "a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess it is but is anyone can confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the time taken by ES to return results using both versions of your code and decide for yourself. In my experience, it would not matter much at all. As long your ES query generation code is clean and simple, stick to it.